# Wacom Intuos BT M tablet input lag

Tags: bluetooth, wacom

I'm using a Wacom Intuos BT M for taking notes etc, e.g. using the "comment" functionality in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Problem is, that the input is severely lagging, not allowing me e.g. to write continuously. I want to use this tablet explicitly wireless (via bluetooth).

Previously, I used an older model of the same tablet (Wacom model CTL-672, connected via USB) and I did not experience these kind of issues. Also, when connecting the new model via USB to the computer, these issues are not present. It hence seems to me that the problem is the bluetooth connection.

I'm using a MacBook pro from 2017 with an i5 and 16GB of RAM, running MacOS 12.5
Besides my Apple Keyboard, no other bluetooth devices are in use.

How can I fix this to get this working properly?

Comment: If you turn off/on the tablet, does the lag continue?

Comment: yes, it does unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fix for this problem - we have to face a sad fact: BT connection is utterly useless on this product, at least a wired connection works fine.

I've tested it on the following systems, and all have the same issue:

- Macbook Pro 2019 i7
- Macbook Pro 2022 M2
- Windows 11 i7 Acer Mini
- Windows 11 i5 Lenovo Legion Desktop

Comment: Wow. I even can confirm it with a MacBook Pro M2 pro